# Naming convention for nonmutating 'add' to a collection

Tags: python, collections, naming-conventions, immutability

I have a class called `Grammar`, which holds a collection of production rules. Before doing things with a `Grammar` object, I usually need to add a few extra rules to it, which should be forgotten after the current task is done. So, I'd like to add a method that returns a new `Grammar` object, containing all the current object's rules as well as the new ones.

I could call this method `.add`, like this:

```
class Grammar:

    def add(self, *rules):
        '''Returns new Grammar object, with 'rules' added.'''
        . . .
```

but `.add` conventionally seems to mean a method that modifies a collection by adding new elements to it.

Is there a naming convention in Python for a method that returns a new collection, with new elements "added", without giving the reader the expectation that it modifies the object?

---

**Operator overloading?**

I know that the `.__add__` method is invoked by the `+` operator, and there the convention is indeed that the object is not modified—like this:

```
working_grammar = grammar + [rule1, rule2, rule3]
```

I am thinking to avoid overloading an operator, in favor of a meaningful method name. However, if the overloaded operator produces conventional, expected, readable code, I'd like to know more about that—perhaps a well-known precedent in a library, or advice in a well-known style guide.

Comment: `def Get_Copy_With_Added_Rules(self, *rules)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I usually name functions with the output. Also, use verb+object. Some suggestions:

- add_rule (or addRule())
- added
- added_rule
- insert

For 'returns a new collection, with new elements "added"'. What is the usual collection? List, tuple, set?

- add_to_rule_list
- add_to_rule_set

You may also follow the [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1):

`concat` comes not only from **Python** but also **C** and **C++**; it means "add the item and then return a reference to the collection", like string concatenation, or array concatenation.

```py
class Grammar:

    def concat(self, rules):
        '''Returns new Grammar object, with 'rules' added.'''


working_grammer = grammar.concat([rule1, rule2, rule3])
```

[pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

You could even extend your `concat` method for arrays of rules and other `Grammar` objects

```py
class Grammar:
    def concat(self, *grammarlike):

grammarC = grammarA.concat(grammarB, [ruleD, ruleE])
```